# How to get the days in a date range that belong to a certain month using Excel?

Tags: datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet that basically looks like this:

```
  | A          | B
1 | 23.12.2013 | 03.01.2014
2 | 20.01.2014 | 25.01.2014
```

and so forth. The dates stored in `start` and `end` could be in the same month but are not necessarily. Simply summing up workdays in a range is not that hard: `=NETWORKDAYS(A1;B1)` is fine here.

So the question is how do I sum up the work days in a range that belong to a certain month? For the first row for example the result would be 7 for December and 3 for January.

Comment: You want to get 7 in a cell and 3 in another cell?

Comment: @Jerry yes - that is basically the goal

Comment: Does your range always lie within 1 or 2 months? Not more?

Comment: @Taosique usually yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if your bounds are in cells `A1` and `A2` and you want to intersect the range with December 2013:

`=NETWORKDAYS(MAX(A1,DATE(2013,12,1)),MIN(A2,DATE(2013,12,31)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using @Taosique's formula (+1) and modifying it a little, you can create a table (which will have to be maintained as and when required) to track such things down.

I would create several columns with headers containing dates, being 1st December 2013, then 1st January 2014, 1st February 2014, etc.

Then in cell C2, use the formula:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(NETWORKDAYS(MAX($A2,C$1),MIN(D$1-1,$B2)),0),0)
```

Then drag it down and across to fill for the other columns (months) and people. See the google spreadsheet I made [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dDlIdVhKWjlkUGNhRjViQUJsYzdnTWc&usp=sharing) if you wan to see it.

Google Spreadsheet has some limitations on formatting, but you can 'hide' the date of the column by turning it into a month by formatting it as `mmm-yy` in Excel.